# sortParamsByRequiredFlag not applied to model generation

Tags: c#, swagger-codegen

I'm using the swagger-codegen to generate c# client, however noticing that the `sortParamsByRequiredFlag` is not applied to model generation.

For example, here is a sample config file:

```
{
    "packageVersion" : "1.0.0",
    "sortParamsByRequiredFlag": true,
    "optionalProjectFile" : false
}
```

Here is the generated truncated code for model's constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="V2alpha1CronJobSpec" /> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ConcurrencyPolicy">Specifies how to treat concurrent executions of a Job. Defaults to Allow..</param>
/// <param name="FailedJobsHistoryLimit">The number of failed finished jobs to retain. This is a pointer to distinguish between explicit zero and not specified..</param>
/// <param name="JobTemplate">Specifies the job that will be created when executing a CronJob. (required).</param>
/// <param name="Schedule">The schedule in Cron format, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron. (required).</param>
/// <param name="StartingDeadlineSeconds">Optional deadline in seconds for starting the job if it misses scheduled time for any reason.  Missed jobs executions will be counted as failed ones..</param>
/// <param name="SuccessfulJobsHistoryLimit">The number of successful finished jobs to retain. This is a pointer to distinguish between explicit zero and not specified..</param>
/// <param name="Suspend">This flag tells the controller to suspend subsequent executions, it does not apply to already started executions.  Defaults to false..</param>
public V2alpha1CronJobSpec(string ConcurrencyPolicy = default(string), int? FailedJobsHistoryLimit = default(int?), V2alpha1JobTemplateSpec JobTemplate = default(V2alpha1JobTemplateSpec), string Schedule = default(string), long? StartingDeadlineSeconds = default(long?), int? SuccessfulJobsHistoryLimit = default(int?), bool? Suspend = default(bool?))
{
    // to ensure "JobTemplate" is required (not null)
    if (JobTemplate == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidDataException("JobTemplate is a required property for V2alpha1CronJobSpec and cannot be null");
    }
    else
    {
        this.JobTemplate = JobTemplate;
    }
    // to ensure "Schedule" is required (not null)
    if (Schedule == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidDataException("Schedule is a required property for V2alpha1CronJobSpec and cannot be null");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Schedule = Schedule;
    }
    this.ConcurrencyPolicy = ConcurrencyPolicy;
    this.FailedJobsHistoryLimit = FailedJobsHistoryLimit;
    this.StartingDeadlineSeconds = StartingDeadlineSeconds;
    this.SuccessfulJobsHistoryLimit = SuccessfulJobsHistoryLimit;
    this.Suspend = Suspend;
}
```

As you can see from the swagger spec, `JobTemplate`, `Schedule` are required parameters. However, the params in the constructor are sorted alphabetically.

I've been sorting through the swagger-codegen code base and I think the `sortParamsByRequiredFlag` only applies to API generated methods.

Is this by design? I'm not sure if I'm missing some config that I should be setting?

[Here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6996) is the GitHub issue I opened but haven't heard anything on it.

Comment: It says it is required, however, the parameter is optional. If the parameter wasn't optional, it'd would not have a choice but to be before all those optional parameters.

Comment: That code is pretty bad to be honest. A required string cannot be empty and it doesn't check that. Also, parameter names should be in `camelCase` not `PascalCase`.

Comment: I agree, the generated code is not very good for the models - it does however conform for the rules when it comes to the API methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to why Swagger is not generating the correct code, but an answer to your problem on GitHub.

There is absolutely no need for you to use this:

```
var jobSpec = new V2alpha1CronJobSpec(null, null, new V2alpha1JobTemplateSpec(), "stringValue", null, ...);
```

You can just use this (called named parameters):

```
var jobSpec = new V2alpha1CronJobSpec(JobTemplate: new V2alpha1JobTemplateSpec(), Schedule: "stringValue");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Camilo! You are right, I could use named parameters and I guess that'll be the way to go for now. It still does not enforce the caller to specify the required arguments (until they hit the exception at runtime) - will have to wait for a response on the swagger issue on github.

Comment: Well, you could do as we all do, and don't use generators. There're enough shortcuts on VS to make writing models easy and fast

Answer (score 0):

For c# client this flag is ignored in the main codebase.
You can create your own extension and override fromModel method to sort the properties.
Have a look at below code on how to do it.

```
@Override
public CodegenModel fromModel(String name, Model model, Map<String, Model> allDefinitions) {
    CodegenModel codegenModel = super.fromModel(name, model, allDefinitions);

    if (sortParamsByRequiredFlag) 
    {
        Collections.sort(codegenModel.readWriteVars, new Comparator<CodegenProperty>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(CodegenProperty one, CodegenProperty another) {
                if (one.required == another.required) return 0;
                else if (one.required) return -1;
                else return 1;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("***Sorting based on required params in model....***");
    }
    return codegenModel;
}
```